# How can I manage to animate my letter with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, animation

I'm interested if how it's possible to make The Diagonal "L" Letter above "Barami" Logo < small logo image in the top left corner can be animated so when I hover on that small logo, the L letter dissapears & starts slowly appearing from left to right, Similar to

```css
 
div { 
display: inline-block; 
overflow: hidden; 
white-space: nowrap; 
animation: example 2s linear 0s infinite alternate; 
} 
@keyframes example { from { width: 0; } to { width: 75px; } }
```

```html
<div>L</div>
```

link : https://www.barami.ge/#main

[image: Logo]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I want to make something like this (But instead of L letter, there should be the Logo which seems similar to diagonal letter 'L')  ----------------- 
<style> 
div {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: example 2s linear 0s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 75px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>L</div>
</body>

Comment: Please paste your code directly into your question and format it correctly, e.g. by using 4 blanks in front of each code line or by using ` around `code`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by animating the width of an absolutely positioned CSS Pseudo Element with a background image, over an image of the logo. Se a rough example in the snippet below.

However, this is just to show you the *gist* of how you could do this. **I highly recommend separating the logo into two images, one with just the "<" swish at the top, and one image with the text**. Nest both images in an element, then position the image with the "<" absolutely at the top of the container, add a bit of extra padding to the top of the parent container, then finally add the animation.

```css
.logo { 
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 158px;
}

.logo:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-image: url(https://www.barami.ge/assets/userarea/logo.png);
  background-size: 300px auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.logo:hover:before {
  animation: example 2s linear 0s infinite alternate;
}

.logo__inner {
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-self: flex-end;
  display: flex;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 158px;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

@keyframes example { 
  from { 
    width: 0; 
  } 
  to { 
    width: 100%; 
  } 
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <div class="logo__inner">
    <img src="https://www.barami.ge/assets/userarea/logo.png">
  </div>
</div>
```